# How to generate an array from multiples properties of a class

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Having a simple model:

```
public class SimpleClass
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set;}
}
```

And a collection:

```
List<SimpleClass> myCollection = new List<SimpleClass>();
```

I want to do the following:

```
var headerCollection = new List<string>();

foreach(var item in myCollection)
{
    headerCollection.add(item.prop1);
    headerCollection.add("Total");
    headerCollection.add("Date");
    //...
    headerCollection.add(item.prop2);
}
```

But I need to use linq to objects.

I tried:

```
var modifiedHeaders = myCollection
    .Select(item => new[] { item.CON_DESCRIPCION, "Total", "Date", item.prop2 });
```

But it generates a collection of type: `List<string[]>`. How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to use `SelectMany` instead of `Select`:

```
var mh = myCollection.SelectMany(i =>
    new[] { i.CON_DESCRIPTION, "Total", "Date", i.prop2 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SelectMany` after `Select`:

```
var modifiedHeaders = myCollection
       .Select(item => new[] { item.CON_DESCRIPCION, "Total", "Date", item.prop2 })
       .SelectMany(x => x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Select to SelectMany:

```
var modifiedHeaders = myCollection
    .SelectMany(item => new[] { item.CON_DESCRIPCION, "Total", "Date", item.prop2 });
```